# How can I format a date coming from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express

I'm using Jade to render my views from within Express.js. I am saving documents in MongoDB and using Mongoose to access my documents. I am saving a default date created when a new document is created and I am returning that date created attribute to the view, where is needs to be formatted. The format of the date being stored within MongoDB is:

```
Thu Dec 29 2011 20:14:56 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

**My question is: How do I format this date in Jade (or Mongoose or Node.JS) coming back from MongoDB?**

Answer (score 62, accepted):

JavaScript has built-in support for dates. First, to get your string into a Date object:

```
date =  new Date('Thu Dec 29 2011 20:14:56 GMT-0600 (CST)')
```

Now you can use various methods on the date to get the data you need:

```
date.toDateString() // "Thu Dec 29 2011"
date.toUTCString()  // "Fri, 30 Dec 2011 02:14:56 GMT"
date.getMonth()     // 11
date.getDate()      // 29
date.getFullYear()  // 2011
```

You can see more methods [on the MDN reference site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You can use these methods to build any kind of string you want.

For more robust date/time parsing, formatting, and manipulation, you should definitely check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) as mentioned by s3v3n in another answer.

Comment: Man, this makes dealing with dates a lot of work when displaying them :(

Comment: As shown, **date.getMonth()** returns 11 for December. You'll probably want to use **date.getMonth()+1** if you are displaying it.

Comment: **getYear()** is deprecated, use **getFullYear()** instead.

Answer (score 65):

I had exactly this requirements (expressjs, mongoose, jade) and this is how I solved it for myself.

First of all I installed [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) with `npm install moment`.
Then I passed moment to view using this:

```
var moment = require('moment');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // find all jobs using mongoose model
    Job.find().exec(function(err, items){
        // pass moment as a variable
        res.render('status', { 'jobs': items, moment: moment });
    })
});
```

Then using it like this in Jade:

```
table
  tr
    td Subject
    td Posted at
    td Status
  each job, i in jobs
    tr
      td #{job.subject}
      td #{moment(job.postedAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}
      td #{job.status}
```

Comment: Awesome! Best answer IMHO!

Comment: @s3v3n You are GOD. This saved my day. Was frustrated for 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 16):

I guess you haven't tried the easy way?

```
#{storeddate.toDateString()}
```

Comment: Or, to drop the day-of-week...

#{storeddate.toDateString().substr(4,12)}

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you don't need another attribute in your Mongoose schema to store the creation date, as the `_id` has that information. Instead, you can create a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html) on your Mongoose schema, like this:

```
YourSchema.virtual('date')
  .get(function() {
    return this._id.generationTime;
  });
```

That would return the raw Javascript date as the `.date` attribute for each document.

Then you can take that one step further and format the date you way you want to in that virtual:

```
YourSchema.virtual('date')
  .get(function() {
    return this._id.generationTime.toDateString();
  });
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that storing the generationTime is redundant, -1 for proposing to create a virtual for date. This is obviously a matter of displaying the value, so the view should handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how can do that (Using EJS)

```
   <%

    var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
    ];

    var d = post.date.getDate();
    var m = monthNames[post.date.getMonth()];
    var y = post.date.getFullYear();

    %>
```

Now You Can Use These Variables Like This...

```
<small style="color: red"><%= post.date  %></small>
```

Source:
https://medium.com/@littlelostify/how-to-format-mongoose-crappy-date-10df67d7a2d6

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

Add [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to your express application locals like this:
`app.locals.moment = require('moment');`

Then you can use moment in any jade files:
`span='(Created at: ' + moment(obj.createTime).format("YYYY/MM/DD") + ')'`

Reference:
[Making use of utility libraries in server-side Jade templates](https://coderwall.com/p/egh53a)

Answer (score 0):

very easy method steps-

1. install via npm moment --save
2. declare var moment = require('moment');
3. define the declare variable in res.render'filename.ejs',{moment: moment});
4. put this ejs in your view file <%= moment(data.column_name_of_your_date).format( 'DD MMM YYYY'); %>

output is --
09 Jun 2017

you can changed the format check it out in moment link for different format http://momentjs.com/