# Convert UTC to localtime best approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Am using:

mongoDB to fetch data to the server which is based on: node.js and express. Template engine is PUG aka. Jade.

in each document stored inside the DB there is a date attribute stored as UTC.

Question/problem.

I need to convert UTC to the clients local-time.

Solving alternatives:

1. Using Aggregation in MongoDB
2. Using moment.js library and make the conversion in node
3. Pass moment.js object inside the view and make the conversion their, 
   **as suggested in this post:** 
   [How can I format a date coming from MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675642/how-can-i-format-a-date-coming-from-mongodb)

Comment: How do you have the client's timezone? In what format?

Comment: I will get the timezone through the browser via the template-engine, sent to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `moment.js` to format an `ISO 8601` date string to local time can be achieved like this:

```
let moment = require('moment');

let localizedDate = moment('2014-06-01T12:00:00Z').format('LT');

console.log(localizedDate);
```